# c++ programming realted , array of numbers

Tags: python, c++

I'm new to c++ .This is the first part of my program.I want the output of list a .But it doesn't give a output.only get  input.After getting inputs the program stops.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class clist {
public:
 int i, j,k,times;
 double numbers[1000];
 clist () {

 }
 clist(int j) {
     k = j;
     cout << "Enter the numbers" << endl;
     for (times = 0; times < k; times++) {
         cin >> numbers[times];
     }
 }
 void print_lista() {
     for (times = 0; times < k; times++) {
         cout << numbers[times] << "\t" << endl;
     }
 }

};
int main()
{
 cout << "Enter how many numbers you want to enter" << endl;
 clist obj;
 cin >> obj.i; 
 clist obj2(obj.i);
 clist obj3;
 obj3.print_lista();
 return 0;
 
}
```

Comment: Why did you tag your question with `python`?

Comment: Why are you creating three objects of type `clist`? When you execute `obj3.print_lista();`, `obj3.k` has not been initialized, so the line `for (times = 0; times < k; times++) {` in the function `print_lista` does not make sense.

Comment: Where do you initialize `k` in the default constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your calling the print list function on obj3 which is empty.
remove obj3, call the function on obj2 and it will work.

it's very sloppy code, I suggest you get a better understanding of c++ before you continue oop.

Comment: OK thank you so much all. I got it